# Implicit Dependecy error when trying to install Firebase Firestore on React Native IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native

I have a React Native project running on 0.72.7 version, running on a IOS simulator and I am trying to integrate it with Firebase, it works fine when i install "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.7.1", but as soon as I try to install "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^18.6.2", or any other feature of Firebase i get the below error.

```html
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace MaskMindsv1.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme MaskMindsv1 -destination id=2931C9D1-FAF3-4ACD-B7D9-4155404A068C

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Prepare packages

ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (70 targets)
    Target 'MaskMindsv1' in project 'MaskMindsv1'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Pods-MaskMindsv1' in project 'Pods' via file 'libPods-MaskMindsv1.a' in build phase 'Link Binary'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'BVLinearGradient' in project 'Pods' via options '-lBVLinearGradient' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'DoubleConversion' in project 'Pods' via options '-lDoubleConversion' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCore' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFirebaseCore' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'FirebaseCoreInternal' in project 'Pods' via options '-lFirebaseCoreInternal' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'GoogleUtilities' in project 'Pods' via options '-lGoogleUtilities' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'PromisesObjC' in project 'Pods' via options '-lPromisesObjC' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCT-Folly' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRCT-Folly' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RCTTypeSafety' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRCTTypeSafety' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNCMaskedView' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNCMaskedView' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNFBApp' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNFBApp' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNGestureHandler' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNGestureHandler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNPermissions' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNPermissions' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNReanimated' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNReanimated' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNScreens' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNScreens' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'RNTextGradientView' in project 'Pods' via options '-lRNTextGradientView' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Codegen' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Codegen' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Core' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Core' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-CoreModules' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-CoreModules' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Fabric' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Fabric' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-FabricImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-FabricImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-ImageManager' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-ImageManager' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-Mapbuffer' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-Mapbuffer' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-NativeModulesApple' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-NativeModulesApple' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAnimation' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTAnimation' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTAppDelegate' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTAppDelegate' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTBlob' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTBlob' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTFabric' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTFabric' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTImage' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTImage' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTLinking' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTLinking' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTNetwork' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTNetwork' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTSettings' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTSettings' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTText' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTText' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-RCTVibration' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-RCTVibration' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-cxxreact' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-cxxreact' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-debug' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-debug' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-graphics' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-graphics' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-hermes' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-hermes' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jserrorhandler' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jserrorhandler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsi' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsi' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsiexecutor' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsiexecutor' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-jsinspector' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-jsinspector' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-logger' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-logger' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-nativeconfig' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-nativeconfig' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-perflogger' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-perflogger' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-rendererdebug' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-rendererdebug' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-runtimescheduler' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-runtimescheduler' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'React-utils' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReact-utils' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'ReactCommon' in project 'Pods' via options '-lReactCommon' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'SocketRocket' in project 'Pods' via options '-lSocketRocket' in build setting 'OTHER_LDFLAGS'
        ➜ Implicit dependency on target 'Yoga' in project 'Pods' via options '-lYoga' in
```

It just gets stuck on the above prompt. Any suggestions as to what i can do to fix it?